# groupby on a multiindex level and dropping the grouping level

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I'm doing a groupby operation on pandas dataframe, which as an example may look like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

numbers = [0, 1, 2]
colors = ['green', 'purple']
mx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([colors, numbers], names=['color', 'numbers'])

values = np.random.rand(6)

df = pd.DataFrame(values, mx)
df = df.drop(index=("green", 2))
```

(index example is from [pandas docs on multiindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html))

Then I want to do a group operation on a level, for instance `"color"`, but I don't want color to remain as an index in the grouped `series`, since it becomes redundant.

```py
for key, series in df.groupby("color"):
    print(f"{key = }")
    print(f"Expected index: {series.index.droplevel('color').to_list()}")
    print(f"Actual index: {series.index.to_list()}")
    print()
```

which outputs:

```
key = 'green'
Expected index: [0, 1]
Actual index: [('green', 0), ('green', 1)]

key = 'purple'
Expected index: [0, 1, 2]
Actual index: [('purple', 0), ('purple', 1), ('purple', 2)]
```

Since the grouped level `"color"` is the same for every grouping, it's redundant, and I just need the level values for `"numbers"`.

I could just drop the level inside the loop as done here, but I was wondering if there were other ways of accomplishing this that I've missed?

Comment: What exactly the operation you're trying to do with `groupby`?

Comment: @QuangHoang In this case I'm looping through groups to plot them, and i need the color (or animal) as the label, the numbers as x and the values as y. But I can imagine there are other use cases.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can simply index your slice of you dataframe with the key:

```
for key, series in df.groupby("color"):
    print(f'Key: {key}')
    print(series.loc[key])
    print('\n')
```

Output:

```
Key: green
                0
numbers          
0        0.913962
1        0.457205


Key: purple
                0
numbers          
0        0.939128
1        0.778389
2        0.715971
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to loop through first level value. You can just try:

```
for color in df.index.get_level_values('color').unique():
    series = df.loc[color]
    print(color)
    print(series)
```

Output:

```
green
                0
numbers          
0        0.161444
1        0.403312
purple
                0
numbers          
0        0.369750
1        0.222223
2        0.565426
```

Comment: Thanks, in my example that would work, but this wouldn't work if I were looking at groups where the label could be two levels. You can also use `df.index.unique("color")`, which would be more readable.